# Capture audio stream from NaCl with Web Audio API?

Tags: html, web-audio-api, google-nativeclient

I have a compiled NaCl module that plays audio directly on the speakers. Is it possible to capture the audio buffer with the Web Audio API, or do I need to get the source code for the NaCl module and modify it (and learn Pepper and C++) to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure (at all) how NaCl works, but https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs can be used to capture audio in Web Audio. It seems likely it'd work in this scenario too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that NaCl sends the audio directly to the speakers, never going through Web Audio. I suppose it is not possible, and that the only way to do this is by modifying the NaCl module.